# Concurrency- Difference between starting thread as it is initialized

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a quick question on concurrency. I am implementing threads and concurrency via the runnable interface. Is there a difference if I first initialize the threads and then call start separately after they have initialized, or if I initialize the threads and call start from within the same for loop?

Here's an example

```
for (int i= 0; i < threads.length; i++)
        threads[i]= new 
        Thread(new RunnableThread(this, urls[i]));

    for (Thread thread : threads)
        thread.start();

    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
```

or

```
 for (int i= 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            threads[i]= new 
            Thread(new RunnableThread(this, urls[i]));
            threads[i].start();

}

        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just FYI, you might want to take a look at java's [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) as it provides a much more efficient and reusable way of spawning and managing threads. In fact, creating threads directly is generally discouraged. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

No difference and you cant predict which thread will start in both the case.

Answer (score 0):

The difference should rely on how your OS implements. But in general, there should be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, there is no difference between the two and regarding the order of execution of threads , you can never predict when the `Scheduler` chooses a thread to execute or in what order they get executed, so it is a good practice to never have your program logic depend on the order of execution of threads

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a general answer, it depends what exactly your `RunnableThread` class *does* in its constructor and its `run` method.  The first approach guarantees that *all* the constructor calls will be complete before *any* of the `run` methods start, the second doesn't.  Whether or not that is important depends on the details of the code.